# Using scanner to read phrases

Tags: parsing, whitespace, java.util.scanner

Hey StackOverflow Community,

So, I have this line of information from a txt file that I need to parse.

Here is an example lines:

->   date & time            AC Power      Insolation     Temperature     Wind Speed
->   mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm.ss          kw           W/m^2           deg F            mph

Using a scanner.nextLine() gives me a String with a whole line in it, and then I pass this off into StringTokenizer, which then separates them into individual Strings using whitespace as a separator.

so for the first line it would break up into:
date
&
time
AC
Power
Insolation
etc...

I need things like "date & time" together, and "AC Power" together. Is there anyway I can specify this using a method already defined in StringTokenizer or Scanner? Or would I have to develop my own algorithm to do this?

Would you guys suggest I use some other form of parsing lines instead of Scanner? Or, is Scanner sufficient enough for my needs?

ejay

Comment: are the tokens like "AC Power" known in advance?

Comment: for this project, no they are not. things like AC Power, Wind Speed, etc. are always subject to change, so even though it's consistent now, the customer may use different fields then "AC Power". So that makes the problem a little more complex.

Comment: uhm, actually this makes the problem impossible, unless you have some magic device to guess the tokens

Comment: okay, so let's say i did know the tokens in advance. then would i just use a String comparison to do it?

Comment: see my answer below, other possibilities: change every token to some var %ACPOWER%, split the String, and change the vars back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh, this one was tricky, maybe you could build up some [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure with your tokens, i was bored and wrote a little class which solves your problem. Warning: it's a bit hacky, but was fun to implement.

The Trie class:

```
class Trie extends HashMap<String, Trie> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    boolean end = false;

    public void addToken(String strings) {
        addToken(strings.split("\\s+"), 0);
    }

    private void addToken(String[] strings, int begin) {
        if (begin == strings.length) {
            end = true;
            return;
        }

        String key = strings[begin];
        Trie t = get(key);
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Trie();
            put(key, t);
        }
        t.addToken(strings, begin + 1);

    }

    public List<String> tokenize(String data) {
        String[] split = data.split("\\s+");
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        int pos = 0;
        while (pos < split.length) {
            int tokenLength = getToken(split, pos, 0);
            tokens.add(glue(split, pos, tokenLength));
            pos += tokenLength;
        }

        return tokens;
    }

    public String glue(String[] parts, int pos, int length) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(parts[pos]);
        for (int i = pos + 1; i < pos + length; i++) {
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(parts[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private int getToken(String[] tokens, int begin, int length) {
        if (end) {
            return length;
        }
        if (begin == tokens.length) {
            return 1;
        }

        String key = tokens[begin];
        Trie t = get(key);
        if (t != null) {
            return t.getToken(tokens, begin + 1, length + 1);
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and how to use it:

```
Trie t = new Trie();
t.addToken("AC Power");
t.addToken("date & time");
t.addToken("date & foo");
t.addToken("Speed & fun");

String data = "date & time AC Power Insolation Temperature Wind Speed";

List<String> tokens = t.tokenize(data);
for (String s : tokens) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```